# Readmore.js script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a quick question regarding readmore.js script.

this is the code:

```
$('article').readmore({maxHeight: 240});
```

which targets everything with an html article tag, but how to I change to just target one article?

thanks!

edit

This is at the end of the html

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/readmore.js"></script>

  <script>
  $('#info').readmore({
    moreLink: '<a href="#">More examples and options</a>',
    maxHeight: 390,
    afterToggle: function(trigger, element, expanded) {
      if(! expanded) { // The "Close" link was clicked
        $('html, body').animate( { scrollTop: element.offset().top }, {duration: 100 } );
      }
    }
  });

    $('article').readmore({maxHeight: 240});
</script>
```

then my articles is set out like this

```html
<article>
<p>loads of text</p>
</article> <!--this article is ok-->

<article>
<p>lots of text</p> <!--this article needs a readmore link -->
```

if I change my article tags to:

```html
<article id="text-one">
<p>loads of text</p>
</article> <!--this article is ok-->

<article id="text-two">
<p>lots of text</p> <!--this article needs a readmore link -->
```

and change the

$('article').readmore({maxHeight: 240});

to

$('#text-two').readmore({maxHeight: 240});

Is this correct?

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Readmore itself but you are just about jquery selectors.

Comment: How do you identify the specific article you're targeting?  Currently `$('article')` selects every `article` element.  Does your specific article have an `id`?  Something else with distinguishes it from other articles?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like readmore uses a framework like jQuery with CSS selectors.

To target a specific article, you simply refine the selector. For example, if you have in your HTML:

```
<article id="my-id">...</article>
```

then you target it with:

```
$('#my-id').readmore(...);
```

since that is the CSS selector which targets an element with a specific ID on the page.

Comment: If it doesn't work then you'll have to show us more of what's going on. 

For example, one way that this could fail is if your `<script>` tag is very high up, say in the `<head>` of the document, while the `<article>` is defined underneath it. Another is if you mistook the `...` above for literal characters rather than a human instruction to "fill in whatever you need to here." StackOverflow is not a game of 20 questions; we cannot problem-solve efficiently if our only responses are "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", ...

Comment: I updated the question, thanks for taking the time to answer Chris, really appreciate it!

Comment: Afraid no joy with id tag. but with the class tag it works! Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score -1):

you can use the following function

**JS CODE**

```
        //read more or less
        function showMoreOrLess(thisObj,bonusContent){
        var caption = thisObj.innerHTML;
        //alert(caption);
        if ( caption == "Read more" ) {
            document.getElementById(bonusContent).style.display = "inline";
            thisObj.innerHTML = "Read less";
        } else {
            document.getElementById(bonusContent).style.display = "none";
            thisObj.innerHTML = "Read more";
        }
    }
```

**HTML CODE**

```
  main text here...
  <a class="read" onclick="showMoreOrLess(this,'moreS1');">Read more</a>

  <span id="moreS1" style="display:none">
    whatever text you need to put here...
  </span>
```